# Clean up some If statements

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to make this more clean and readable? It's just some `If` statements which check if values of an array are zero. If the values are zero it would clean some cells, if not it would do some math with the values and write the solution into the cells instead of cleaning them.

```
            If varItem(3) = 0 Then
                .Cells(i + 1, intColumn).Value = ""
                .Cells(i + 2, intColumn).Value = ""
            Else
                .Cells(i + 1, intColumn).Value = varItem(3)                                        ' Stock on Hand
                .Cells(i + 2, intColumn).Value = "=N" & i + 1 & "-N" & i + 3 & "-N" & i + 4        ' Formula for Healthy Stock (SoH - ExV - Inac)
            End

            If varItem(4) = 0 Then
                .Cells(i + 3, intColumn).Value = ""
            Else
                .Cells(i + 3, intColumn).Value = varItem(4)                                        ' Excess Value
            End

            If varItem(5) = 0 Then
                .Cells(i + 4, intColumn).Value = ""
            Else
                .Cells(i + 4, intColumn).Value = varItem(5)                                        ' Inactive Value
            End If

            If varItem(6) = 0 Then
                 .Cells(i + 5, intColumn).Value = ""
            Else
                .Cells(i + 5, intColumn).Value = varItem(6)                                        ' Inactive 12M Value
            End


            If varItem(2) = 0 Or varItem(3) = 0 Then
                .Cells(intRow, 20).Value = ""
                .Cells(intRow, 21).Value = ""
            Else
                .Cells(intRow, 20).Value = varItem(2) / varItem(3)              ' Stockturn
                .Cells(intRow, 21).Value = varItem(3) / (varItem(2) / 365)      ' Days of Inventory
            End If

            If varItem(1) = 0 Or varItem(2) = 0 Then
                .Cells(intRow, 22).Value = ""
            Else
                .Cells(intRow, 22).Value = varItem(1) / varItem(2)              ' Safety Stock Value
            End If

            If varItem(4) = 0 Or varItem(5) = 0 Then
                .Cells(intRow, 23).Value = ""
            Else
                .Cells(intRow, 23).Value = varItem(4) / varItem(3)              ' Excess Value in %
            End If

            If varItem(6) = 0 And varItem(3) = 0 Then
                .Cells(intRow, 24).Value = ""
            Else
                .Cells(intRow, 24).Value = varItem(6) / varItem(3)              ' Inactive 12M Stock Value in %
            End
```

Comment: What if you made the number inside the `varItem()` into an integer and then loop through them? It seems like the code inside thse `IF` statements uses `i + (n-1)`, so you could do something like: `For n = 3 to 6...`  I realize that doesn't totally work, but it's a start.

Comment: I think we'd need to see more context to answer this. I assume `i` is a loop of some sort. One thing you could consider is just clearing every cell in one command at the top, then only populating them if the array elements are `<>0`. That would clean it up a bit.

Comment: thanks to all of you, you helped me with the cleaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        ' Stock on Hand
        .Cells(i + 1, intColumn).Value = EmptyIfZero(varItem(3))            
        If varItem(3) = 0 Then
            .Cells(i + 2, intColumn).Value = ""
        Else
            ' Formula for Healthy Stock (SoH - ExV - Inac)
            .Cells(i + 2, intColumn).Value = "=N" & i + 1 & "-N" & i + 3 & "-N" & i + 4        
        End
        'Excess Value
        .Cells(i + 3, intColumn).Value = EmptyIfZero(varItem(4))
        'Inactive Value
        .Cells(i + 4, intColumn).Value = EmptyIfZero(varItem(5)) 
        'Inactive 12M Value                              
        .Cells(i + 5, intColumn).Value = EmptyIfZero(varItem(6))                                        

        'Stockturn
        .Cells(intRow, 20).Value = DivisionIfNotZero(varItem(2),varItem(3) )
        If varItem(2) = 0 Or varItem(3) = 0 Then
            .Cells(intRow, 21).Value = ""
        Else
            ' Days of Inventory
            .Cells(intRow, 21).Value = varItem(3) / (varItem(2) / 365)      
        End If
        ' Safety Stock Value
        .Cells(intRow, 22).Value = DivisionIfNotZero(varItem(1),varItem(2) )               

        'is this intentional? varItem(5) and  varItem(3) 
        If varItem(4) = 0 Or varItem(5) = 0 Then
            .Cells(intRow, 23).Value = ""
        Else
            ' Excess Value in %
            .Cells(intRow, 23).Value = varItem(4) / varItem(3)              
        End If
        ' Inactive 12M Stock Value in %
        .Cells(intRow, 24).Value = DivisionIfNotZero(varItem(6),varItem(3) )             



function EmptyIfZero(variant1)
    If variant1 = 0 then
        EmptyIfZero = ""
    else
        EmptyIfZero = variant1
    end if
end function

function DivisionIfNotZero(variant1,variant2)
    If variant1 = 0 or variant2 = 0 then
        DivisionIfNotZero= ""
    else
        DivisionIfNotZero= variant1/variant2
    end if
end function
```